# Python - json.loads large file of dictionaries that are not connected

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a large (50,000+ lines) file that is a collection of json outputs from another application that i would like to read in as json and perform some analysis on. The issue is that while a single entry is valid json, I can't read the entire file in as json because each entry isn't connected.

Snippet:

```
{"action":"Iops","idg":"2214472975167211","idx":537994,"system":"Qos","utc":"2019-07-02T11:45:09.606765Z","ver":"1.1","xQosIops":{"ActualReadOps":{"avg":0,"ct":60,"max":0,"min":0,"std":0,"tmax":29880,"tmin":29880}}}
{"action":"Latency","idg":"2214472975167211","idx":537995,"system":"Qos","utc":"2019-07-02T11:45:09.606829Z","ver":"1.1","xQosLatency":{"AverageLocalWriteLatencyUS":{"avg":0,"ct":60,"max":0,"min":0,"std":0,"tmax":29880,"tmin":29880}}}
```

Individually they are both valid, but what I would like to achieve is dynamically connect all of these into a single json object. It is important to note that these json responses could span multiple lines, so I can't just read in line by line. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the contents of the file with vanilla Python (not using the `json` package), then use `json` to parse each individual line.

Example:

```
import json

data_fp = "/path/to/data.txt"

with open(data_fp, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# now, parse each line as a JSON string
json_object = [json.loads(l) for l in line]

# optional: dump as a JSON file
with open("/path/to/output.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(json_object, f)
```

**Edit:** if each dictionary is not necessarily limited to a single line, you could try parsing JSON for a variable number of lines until it succeeds (continuing from above example):

```
start_line = 0
end_line = 1
json_object = []
while end_line <= len(lines):
    try:
        data = json.loads("".join(lines[start_line:end_line]))
    except:
        end_line += 1
    else:
        json_object.append(data)
        start_line = end_line
        end_line = start_line + 1
```

Comment: Output could span multiple lines however.

Answer (score 0):

If each line is valid JSON, you could wrap this in a script that read them in individually, and appended them to a list. Something like:

```
import json

data = []

with open("fakejson.txt") as data_f:
    for line in data_f:
        data.append(json.loads(line)
```

Comment: Each line isn't necessarily a new entry, a single output could span multiple lines unfortunately.

Comment: You're probably going to have to walk through the file, using a stack to match opening and closing braces and strings  (`{}`, `[]`, `""`) to identify uniquely valid json objects. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991917/indices-of-matching-parentheses-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that recognizes a json, by looking for pairs of open-close {}. See below:

```
def isjson(t):
    for i in range(len(t)):
        if t[i]=='{':
            s=t[i]
            c=1
            n=1
            while c>0:
                s+=t[i+n]
                if t[i+n]=='{':
                    c+=1
                elif t[i+n]=='}':
                    c-=1
                n+=1
            return (s, i+n)
```

You can now load your entire file as text with the following:

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    t=f.read()
```

And extact all jsons, using the above function:

```
d={}

n=1
while True:
   d[n]=isjson(t)[0]
   t=t[isjson(t)[1]+1:]
   n+=1
   if t.count('{')==0:
       break
```